# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'year' while using timesince

Tags: django, object, django-views, attributes, django-queryset

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'year'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/
Django Version: 2.2.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'year'
```

**models.py**

```
joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
```

**views.py**

```
date_joined = User.objects.order_by('-date_joined')
```

**html**

```
{{ date_joined|timesince }}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include the relevant section of your code.

Answer (score 2):

`date_joined` is a queryset, **not a single** `User` object, so you can't use `timesince` template tag on it.

You should probably loop over the users, or alternatively, send a *single* `User` object to the template and use `timesince` on the **DateTimeField**, not the object itself:

```
{% for user in date_joined %}
    {{ user.joined_date|timesince }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably making a mistake on the data type on your model. For instance, there is no such 'data type' as 'year.

You should check this website to data types for Django: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-model-data-types-and-fields-list/

Also, If you share the relevant part of your code (possibly models.py), we can help you better. All the best!